# Eclipse regex for finding the following string

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I want to search all files in my project in eclipse and replace all occurences of `ConnectionID="lettersandnumbers"`

what is the regex for the bit between the quotation marks(including the quotations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you want to replace the String contents, look for

```
(ConnectionID=").*?(")
```

and replace with

```
$1replacement$2
```

where replacement is what you want to replace the String with :-)

Comment: Um, why capture a fixed string?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ConnectionID="[\p{L}\p{N}]*"
```

This will match all Unicode letters and numbers. Remember, `à` is a letter too.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your search box:

```
ConnectionID=\"[\w]+\"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would search for:

`ConnectionID="(.*)"`

If you're not interested in keeping the chars between quotes you can use

`ConnectionID=".*"`